# Running JasperViewer on Tomcat as part of a web application

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I have learned that *JasperViewer* (default preview component of *JasperReports*) is a *Swing* component, so is there any way to convert or embed it in a web application? Some say I should use *Java Web Start*, but from what i have learned from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) *JWS* is useful to download and install an application on client machine and this is not our case. the other work around that it may work (maybe just in theory) is converting *jFrame* to *jApplet* as briefly described [in this link](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~wchapman/COP2800/misc/Assn6-hints.pdf)

1. Have you tried any of these solutions and did they work?
2. Do you know any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Even an applet would be client side. The Client would have to download all the requisite code from your server to run it local in his applet-sandbox. I do not think that you really want to do this. ... Is there any reason to create a preview via jasperViewer? Why you do not create a pdf (or xls or whatever) and forward this to the client via servlet?

Comment: for preview , we need something more than just a pdf show, we also need export , save as and .. and they are already implemented in jasperViewer.

Comment: JasperViewer is not really meant to be used for production, it is limited and not (easily) customizable. It is probably possible to deploy it using JWS but you will run into all sorts of issues (code signing, java versions, ...)

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to generate a report, you can easily do it inside a servlet and send the generated file to the client. Using a JWS application or an Applet would most likely mean that the report is generated client-side and that the raw data plus all the dependencies are also available to the client.

The code below assumes that you're generating a PDF file

```
public class ReportServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        // initialize your report objects here
        JasperReport jasperReport = 
        JasperPrint print = 

        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print); 
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, resp.getOutputStream()); 

        resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
        exporter.exportReport();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error generating report : " + e.getClass() + " " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

You can extend the example above to support multiple export formats by setting the correct content type and using the matching JRXYZExporter (JRHtmlExporter, JExcelApiExporter,...)

If you need something more customizable, you might also want to look into [Jasper Server](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server)